# WSO2 IS 5.0.0 error thrown then logging in as locked user

Tags: wso2-identity-server

When using WSO2 IS 5.0.0 and setting a user account to locked,  http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked, we get this error below when the login page posts back.

```
Authentication Error !
Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again.
```

If the user is unlocked and login is re-attempted they will login successfully.

When looking at the wso2carbon.log on the IS we only see this error message recorded.

```
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener} -  User account is locked for user : <user>. cannot login until the account is unlocked  {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener}
```

Is there a way to prevent this exception or to catch it so that the login page is not replaced with an exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity Server Login page resides in authentication-endpoint web app[1]. Login fail can be occurred due to reasons such as invalid credentials, invalid user and account Lock. It can be configured Identity server to send exact reason of login failure [2].

So, web app can be customized based on the login failure. (In your case account locking)

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Login+Pages
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Error+Messages